# JSON.parse to array

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json object:

```
var deniedTimeIDs = JSON.parse('[808,809,812,811,814,815]');
```

so, I want to add/remove data from this object by jquery. How to do it? can I convert it to Array?
Thanks

Comment: Please show your JSON data, not your server code. We can't guess what it looks like.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to parse? JSON.parse parses a String representation of json object and converts into an actual json object. What you have passed, is not a json String.

Comment: Your code actually works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/Q7Sp5/

Comment: Then your `deniedTimeIDs` already holds a valid array after executing the above. You can consume it readily thereafter.

Comment: how to add / delete data to this?

Comment: @John Add/remove with splice http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below will give you a javascript object,

```
var deniedTimeIDs = JSON.parse('[808,809,812,811,814,815]');
```

You can then use [.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) &  [.pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to add/remove element into the array.

```
deniedTimeIDs.push(100); //will result in [808,809,812,811,814,815,100]
```

Further Readings,

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON#Example), [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [Array.pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Answer (score 4):

Any Array returned after parsing the String, can be processed with jQuery or JavaScript.
We generally use Push() and Pop() function to process any array.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var deniedTimeIDs = JSON.parse('[808,809,812,811,814,815]');
    // You can use push/Pop to remove the IDs from an array.
    console.log(deniedTimeIDs);// o/p=> [808,809,812,811,814,815]
    //You can iterate this array using jQuery.
    $.each(deniedTimeIDs,function(key,val){
        console.log(val); 
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to parse that String and represent it as an Array you can do the following:

```
// Warning: eval is weird
var arr = eval('[808,809,812,811,814,815]');
```

or

```
var arr= JSON.parse('[808,809,812,811,814,815]');
```

Now `arr` is a valid JavaScript array.

**UPDATE FROM 2021 ADDING AN OFFICIAL DOC ARTICLE WHICH EXPLAINS WHY `eval()` IS A DANGEROUS FUNCTION TO CALL:**

[eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Answer (score 1):

```
var deniedTimeIDs = $.parseJSON('[808,809,812,811,814,815]');
```